# superキーワードとthisキーワードの違いについて

Tags: java

Transformerという抽象クラスを作り、それを継承するDecepticonクラスとAutobotクラスを作りました。その際、下記のコードのようにTransformer抽象クラスに作ったフィールドをDecepticonクラスとAutobotクラスのコンストラクタ内でthisキーワードを使って各々のフィールドにセットできました。しかし、thisキーワードをsuperに置き換えても上手くいきました。
superにすると、Transformer抽象クラスのフィールドの値を書き換えているように思ったのですが、これはなぜでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
public abstract class Transformer {

  public int Strength;
  public int Intelligence;
  public int Speed;
  public int Endurance;
  public int Rank;
  public int Courage;
  public int Firepower;
  public int Skill;

  public abstract int calcOverall();

}
```

```
public class Decepticon extends Transformer {

  Decepticon(int Strength, int Intelligence, int Speed, int Endurance, int Rank, int Courage, int Firepower, int Skill) {
    this.Strength = Strength;
    this.Intelligence = Intelligence;
    this.Speed = Speed;
    this.Endurance = Endurance;
    this.Rank = Rank;
    this.Courage = Courage;
    this.Firepower = Firepower;
    this.Skill = Skill;
  }

  @Override
  public int calcOverall() {
    int result = Strength + Intelligence + Speed + Endurance + Firepower;
    return result;
    }
  }
```

```
public class Soundwave extends Decepticon {

    Soundwave(int Strength, int Intelligence, int Speed, int Endurance, int Rank, int Courage, int Firepower, int Skill) {
      super(Strength, Intelligence, Speed, Endurance, Rank, Courage, Firepower, Skill);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一般にクラス`A`をクラス`B`が継承するとき、単に同名のメソッドやフィールドを持つというよりは、クラス`B`がクラス`A`の**一種**であることを示唆します。言い換えると、クラス`B`はクラス`A`と見なすこともできるということです。
卑近な例を持ち出しますと、"動物"抽象クラスがあるとして、"犬"クラスはそれを継承するクラスとして定義できるでしょう。なぜなら"犬"は"動物"の一種であるからです。

今`Transformer`でいくつかのフィールドを定義しましたが、`Decepticon`や`Soundwave`でもそれらのフィールドが使えるのは、これらのクラスが`Transformer`の一種であるからです。あくまで`Transformer`固有の性質としてそれらのフィールドを持っているわけです。

それゆえ、`Transformer`の`Strength`、`Decepticon`の`Strength`という風に別々に管理されることはありません。それらは同じものを別の側面（それぞれのクラス）から見ているに過ぎないのです。

継承元と継承先のフィールドが「同じ」というのは次のようなコードを考えるとわかりやすいかもしれません。`B`側で設定した値が`A`側でも見えています。

```
abstract class A {
    int field;
}

class B extends A {
    B(int f) {
        this.field = f;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(42);
        System.out.println(b.field);
        // -> 42
        A a = b; // BをAとみなす
        System.out.println(a.field);
        // -> 42
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

次のようにイメージすると分かりやすいのではないかと思います:

- `this`: **自分から**探し始める。無ければ順に継承元を辿っていく。
- `super`: **親から**探し始める。無ければ順に継承元を辿っていく。

---

例えば`Decepticon`インスタンス内で `this.Strength`と指定した場合、

1. 自分、すなわち `Decepticon`で定義された`Strength`フィールドを探す

   - 無いので親(`Transformer`)へ
2. `Transformer`で定義された`Strength`フィールドを探す

   - 存在するので`this.Strength`が指すのはこれである

という探索を行うイメージです。

一方`Decepticon`インスタンス内で `super.Strength`と指定した場合は、

1. 親、すなわち`Transformer`で定義された`Strength`フィールドを探す

   - 存在するので`super.Strength`が指すのはこれである

というイメージになります。

**結果として、今回の場合では** `this.Strength`, `super.Strength`ともに同じく "*`Transformer`で定義された`Strength`フィールド*" を指すことになります。

---

次のような場合だと、`this`, `super`の指すものが変わります。

`Child.java`:

```
abstract class Parent {

    // ↓をコメントアウトすると super.text を指すものがないのでコンパイルエラー
    public String text = "PARENT";

}

public class Child extends Parent {

    // ↓のコメントアウトを外すと this.text と super.text の指すものが変わります
    // public String text = "CHILD";

    private void exec() {

        System.out.println(this.text);
        System.out.println(super.text);

        super.text = "MODIFIED!!!";
        System.out.println("----");

        System.out.println(this.text);
        System.out.println(super.text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child().exec();
    }
}
```

---

英語になりますが、次の公式チュートリアルが今回の事象についてまさに説明している箇所です:

- The Java™ Tutorials

  - [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
  - [Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)
  - [Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)